# Маршруты в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Имеется в папке public файл rss.xml

Могу ли я его открыть через URL?

```
Route::get('/rss', function () {
    return redirect('/public/Rss.xml');
});
```

и

```
Route::get('/rss', function () {
    return redirect('/../public/Rss.xml');
});
```

не проходят

Ссылка вроде идёт, а ничего не открывается.. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public` это "основная" директория? Или файл лежит в `public\public`? Попробуйте указать маршрут без `public`.

```
return redirect('/rss.xml');
```

Comment: Да, заработало. Спасибо большое!